# Use ShowcaseView without the highlight circle

Tags: android, showcaseview

I want to use the `ShowcaseView` library to create a tutorial, but for one stage of the tutorial I **don't want to highlight** anything with the circle.  Is this possible with the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main way to do this is to set the target as [`Target.NONE`](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/targets/Target.java#L6), an example of which is shown in the [sample](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/animations/AnimationSampleActivity.java#L63).

Comment: This is answer is useful. I tried putting null to setShowcase(target ,boolean); but gives me a null pointer exception. It took me a long time to figure that i can put "Target.NONE" instead

Answer (score 1):

As `@maxcanna` points out [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/pull/69), you can call `showcaseView.setShowcaseIndicatorScale(0)` after creating the `ShowcaseView` to accomplish this.

Comment: There's a more standard way in the API, please see my answer!

Comment: @AlexCurran I will note that if you are using `version < 5`, which I currently am for the ghostly hand, then the accepted answer will not work so this answer should be used as a fallback.  Correct me if I am wrong Alex.